# Proving the discontinuity of $g(x)=\sqrt{2+\tan^2x}$ without the aid of a graph

Tags: limits, functions

How would you show where the discontinuity of $g(x)=\sqrt{2+\tan^2x}$ is without a graph?  What sort of approach would you take mathematically?

For example, using the method for piece-wise functions.

Say we have the function,

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, &  x  \leqslant 0\\
2,& x > 0
\end{cases}
$$

We can see the function is discontinuous about $x=0$ by considering,

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}f(x) = 1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x) = 2$

Comment: The function $g$ is continuous wherever it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider the left- and right-hand limits at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: I get that the function is discontinuous at $\frac{\pi}{2} \pm \pi$, I was just wondering if you could prove it with a bit more rigor?

Comment: @Phil_P Definition of continuity is that the limit must agree with the function value. But $f$ is undefined at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.